# Azure Data Factory Data Flow CSV schema drift to parquet static destination dropping columns. Is it possible?

Tags: azure-data-factory

Trying to write a Azure Data Factory Data Flow that would handle two similar versioned CSV files. Version 1 file has 48 columns. Version 2 file has 50 columns – same 48 columns as version 1 but has 2 additional columns appended to the end. I’d like to create a destination parquet file that contains all 50 columns to load into my SQLDW via polybase. Historically we have over 6 thousand files in the same blob source with no easy way to identify files with 48 columns vs 50 columns. Below is the closest I’ve come to a solution.

1. Source CSV with Allow schema drift enabled. No schema defined on the CSV data set
2. MapDrifted derived columns – i.e toString(byName('Manufacturer')) all 50 columns
3. Sink  – data set is parquet with schema defined by parquet template file which contains all 50 columns. Sink partition is set by sourcefilename. Each file coming in will have a parquet file generated in the output.

This solution works with a set of two test files. One with 48 columns and one with 50 columns. Two parquet files are created with 50 columns. One file is populated up to the 48th column the other file is populated with all 50 columns. If I add more source files with 48 columns to the test. The file with 50 columns looses the last two columns of data and only ends up with 48 columns in it? I thought this would be a common issue that ADF could solve. i.e file version changes over time. Any suggestions? Below is a a script of my ADF

```
source(allowSchemaDrift: true,
    validateSchema: false,
    rowUrlColumn: 'sourcefilename',
    inferDriftedColumnTypes: true,
    multiLineRow: true,
    wildcardPaths:['avail/archive_csv2/*.csv']) ~> SRCAvailCSV
SRCAvailCSV derive(Manufacturer = toString(byName('Manufacturer')),
        SKU = toString(byName('SKU')),
        {Partner Name} = toString(byName('Partner Name')),
        {Partner Part Number} = toString(byName('Partner Part Number')),
        {Search Date} = toString(byName('Search Date')),
        {Search Result Description} = toString(byName('Search Result Description')),
        {1st Line Description} = toString(byName('1st Line Description')),
        {2nd Line Description} = toString(byName('2nd Line Description')),
        {Product Category} = toString(byName('Product Category')),
        {Product Category 1} = toString(byName('Product Category 1')),
        {Product Category 2} = toString(byName('Product Category 2')),
        {Product Category 3} = toString(byName('Product Category 3')),
        {Product Category 4} = toString(byName('Product Category 4')),
        {UNSPSC Code} = toString(byName('UNSPSC Code')),
        Pricing = toString(byName('Pricing')),
        Currency = toString(byName('Currency')),
        {Availability Qty} = toString(byName('Availability Qty')),
        {Availability Status} = toString(byName('Availability Status')),
        {Average Rating} = toString(byName('Average Rating')),
        {Total Reviews} = toString(byName('Total Reviews')),
        Brand = toString(byName('Brand')),
        Model = toString(byName('Model')),
        {Product Line} = toString(byName('Product Line')),
        {Partner Site} = toString(byName('Partner Site')),
        {Product URL} = toString(byName('Product URL')),
        Warranty = toString(byName('Warranty')),
        {Product Length} = toString(byName('Product Length')),
        {Product Width} = toString(byName('Product Width')),
        {Product Height} = toString(byName('Product Height')),
        {Product Depth} = toString(byName('Product Depth')),
        {Product Weight} = toString(byName('Product Weight')),
        {Fullfilling Partner} = toString(byName('Fullfilling Partner')),
        {Date First Available} = toString(byName('Date First Available')),
        {Frequently Bought Together 1} = toString(byName('Frequently Bought Together 1')),
        {Frequently Bought Together 1 Part Number} = toString(byName('Frequently Bought Together 1 Part Number')),
        {Frequently Bought Together 2} = toString(byName('Frequently Bought Together 2')),
        {Frequently Bought Together 2 Part Number} = toString(byName('Frequently Bought Together 2 Part Number')),
        {Frequently Bought Together 3} = toString(byName('Frequently Bought Together 3')),
        {Frequently Bought Together 3 Part Number} = toString(byName('Frequently Bought Together 3 Part Number')),
        {Frequently Bought Together 4} = toString(byName('Frequently Bought Together 4')),
        {Frequently Bought Together 4 Part Number} = toString(byName('Frequently Bought Together 4 Part Number')),
        {From the Manufacturer} = toString(byName('From the Manufacturer')),
        {Bestesellers Rank 1} = toString(byName('Bestesellers Rank 1')),
        {Bestsellers Rank 2} = toString(byName('Bestsellers Rank 2')),
        {Bestsellers Rank 3} = toString(byName('Bestsellers Rank 3')),
        {Bestsellers Rank 4} = toString(byName('Bestsellers Rank 4')),
        Endpoint = toString(byName('Endpoint')),
        {Related StarTech.com SKU} = toString(byName('Related StarTech.com SKU')),
        {Search SKU} = toString(byName('Search SKU')),
        {Search Manufacturer} = toString(byName('Search Manufacturer')),
        sourcefilename = sourcefilename) ~> MapDrifted1
MapDrifted1 sink(input(
        FileName as string,
        Manufacturer as string,
        SKU as string,
        PartnerName as string,
        PartnerPartNumber as string,
        SearchDate as string,
        SearchResultDescription as string,
        {1stLineDescription} as string,
        {2ndLineDescription} as string,
        ProductCategory as string,
        ProductCategory1 as string,
        ProductCategory2 as string,
        ProductCategory3 as string,
        ProductCategory4 as string,
        UNSPSCCode as string,
        Pricing as string,
        Currency as string,
        AvailabilityQty as string,
        AvailabilityStatus as string,
        AverageRating as string,
        TotalReviews as string,
        Brand as string,
        Model as string,
        ProductLine as string,
        PartnerSite as string,
        ProductURL as string,
        Warranty as string,
        ProductLength as string,
        ProductWidth as string,
        ProductHeight as string,
        ProductDepth as string,
        ProductWeight as string,
        FullfillingPartner as string,
        DateFirstAvailable as string,
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether1 as string,
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether1PartNumber as string,
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether2 as string,
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether2PartNumber as string,
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether3 as string,
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether3PartNumber as string,
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether4 as string,
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether4PartNumber as string,
        FromtheManufacturer as string,
        BestesellersRank1 as string,
        BestsellersRank2 as string,
        BestsellersRank3 as string,
        BestsellersRank4 as string,
        Endpoint as string,
        RelatedStarTechcomSKU as string,
        SearchSKU as string,
        SearchManufacturer as string
    ),
    allowSchemaDrift: false,
    validateSchema: false,
    format: 'parquet',
    rowUrlColumn:'sourcefilename',
    mapColumn(
        FileName = sourcefilename,
        Manufacturer,
        SKU,
        PartnerName = {Partner Name},
        PartnerPartNumber = {Partner Part Number},
        SearchDate = {Search Date},
        SearchResultDescription = {Search Result Description},
        {1stLineDescription} = {1st Line Description},
        {2ndLineDescription} = {2nd Line Description},
        ProductCategory = {Product Category},
        ProductCategory1 = {Product Category 1},
        ProductCategory2 = {Product Category 2},
        ProductCategory3 = {Product Category 3},
        ProductCategory4 = {Product Category 4},
        UNSPSCCode = {UNSPSC Code},
        Pricing,
        Currency,
        AvailabilityQty = {Availability Qty},
        AvailabilityStatus = {Availability Status},
        AverageRating = {Average Rating},
        TotalReviews = {Total Reviews},
        Brand,
        Model,
        ProductLine = {Product Line},
        PartnerSite = {Partner Site},
        ProductURL = {Product URL},
        Warranty,
        ProductLength = {Product Length},
        ProductWidth = {Product Width},
        ProductHeight = {Product Height},
        ProductDepth = {Product Depth},
        ProductWeight = {Product Weight},
        FullfillingPartner = {Fullfilling Partner},
        DateFirstAvailable = {Date First Available},
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether1 = {Frequently Bought Together 1},
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether1PartNumber = {Frequently Bought Together 1 Part Number},
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether2 = {Frequently Bought Together 2},
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether2PartNumber = {Frequently Bought Together 2 Part Number},
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether3 = {Frequently Bought Together 3},
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether3PartNumber = {Frequently Bought Together 3 Part Number},
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether4 = {Frequently Bought Together 4},
        FrequentlyBoughtTogether4PartNumber = {Frequently Bought Together 4 Part Number},
        FromtheManufacturer = {From the Manufacturer},
        BestesellersRank1 = {Bestesellers Rank 1},
        BestsellersRank2 = {Bestsellers Rank 2},
        BestsellersRank3 = {Bestsellers Rank 3},
        BestsellersRank4 = {Bestsellers Rank 4},
        Endpoint,
        RelatedStarTechcomSKU = {Related StarTech.com SKU},
        SearchSKU = {Search SKU},
        SearchManufacturer = {Search Manufacturer}
    )) ~> sink1
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you *always* wish to output a Parquet file with the same schema? I.e. 50 cols, regardless of schema of incoming file?

If so, what you can do is create a data flow with a "canonical model" that defines this 50-column structure.

You would build your target schema definition using a Derived Column and map your incoming source columns there. If you do not have a matching column, you can just set to NULL.

With this method, you would not need to define a dataset format in the sink. You could just use Auto Map with a blank dataset and output Parquet files.

The Parquet file output schema would match your Derived Column model which would define the friendly alias names you used in your Sink mapping above.

Here's a video I made to help explain this method: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5tgzLjEE9Q.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Yes - regardless of the incoming schema we always want to produce a parquet file with 50 columns. I'm still seeing the behavior we saw before. if the source only has one file with 50 columns all 50 come through on the destination parquet. If the source has a mix of files with 48 and 50 columns files with 50 columns miss data in the last two columns? All sink files do have 50 columns. Source is CSV with no schema. Allow schema drift selected. Derived column has 50 mappings i.e. toString(byName('Manufacturer')). Sink allow schema drift. No schema defined. Auto mapping is turned off.

Comment: That is because byName() is not finding a match for those 2 fields sometimes. You need to set those 2 additional columns to null() in order to write them.

Comment: Do you have an example of the code for setting the column to null()? I'm assuming you would do this when you define the derived column? i.e  iifNull(toString(byName('column')),null()). What I'm confused about is the byName() should be finding the columns and it doesn't. The source data preview reads the first couple of files in the blob. These files have 48 columns. It looks like it’s defining a schema of 48 columns. The file that has 50 columns might be the 10th file in the blob. The data factory doesn’t seem to be adjusting the schema to see the additional columns when it loads the 10th file

Comment: Check the data preview output. Do the extra 2 columns have the "schema drift" icon in the header? If they are drifted columns, you will need to turn on "schema drift" on the sink to get them to write.

Comment: The null() code is correct. I just suggest manually casting the null(): toString(null())

Comment: I reached out to Microsoft and this is their response - The current scenario is not supported by design. This is because we are reading in the first X rows to determine the schema / any drifted columns for the source dataset. Since the majority of the source rows that you are processing only contains the 48 columns, we are determining these 48 columns to be the columns of the source. Once we get to the files with the 50 columns, we still assume that these 48 columns are the ones that make up the schema.

Comment: This is very possible in data flows and we do not require you to use the first x rows to determine your schema. I will record a video and document for you an example then post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I threw together a very quick, very simple demo here: http://youtu.be/DhscTC6VwwI?hd=1.

I added it to our collection of ADF data flow videos because this is a common pattern and leverages schema drift and flexible schema handling.

The key to make this work is to build your output model inside the data flow with derived column. Keep your datasets schemaless.

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Hi Mark - this is a great video and explains the concept very well. Thank you. The difference between my scenario and the one in the video is I iterate over all the mixed column files in one blob where you pause and do one version of each file per Data Factory run. If you were to replicate your moivessmall data to multiple small files (3 columns) i.e. movies1.csv, movies2.csv, movies3.csv and include the one moviesbig.csv(6 columns) into the same blob then run your DF against that. Your Myfile123.csv will only have three columns populated with data. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: To make this technique work, just change your Sink to "Automap". Based on your script from above, it looks like you are manually mapping the columns, which is probably the problem.